# Particle Systems breaking mesh

Tags: modeling

I have created ocean using ocean modifier on 6 different cubes and used particle system (on other plane) for rainfall and trying to get ripple effect of rain on ocean water. But when the particles are falling on the ocean, they are breaking my oceans mesh apart (as per screen shot)

When I remove the particle system, it does not break the ocean mesh and works perfectly.  Can you guys help me how to connect the different oceans together so that when particle systems (object) fall on ocean it shouldn't break.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately you didn’t show us any settings so providing your blend files would help us figuring out your mistake

Comment: If I understand it correctly you use particle systems for a ripple effect, i.e. deformation of the ocean mesh. So deformation will change the mesh, the position of vertices. When those meshes are not connected, they will deform independent from each other and so it will show the gaps between them. To avoid that I guess it would be best if the meshes were joined...